# Should SmtpClient be created (and disposed) per message?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

What is the proper way of using SmtpClient in terms of creating/disposing the object. I have one SmtpClient per message, but not sure if this is correct if I want to send multiple emails. Perhaps it's more efficient/proper to create the client, send multiple message and then dispose?

```
public void SendMail(MailMessage mail)
{
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the [`SmtpClient`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,965), it seems it is built to have multiple connections open. It doesn't seem a problem to me to use that to send multiple messages in a tight loop (don't let the object alive for hours, dispose it as soon you are ready sending).

Creating and disposing the object may have a negative impact on your performance, so that would be a good reason not to create a lot of objects.

Comment: Most examples I saw do dispose it right away for some reason, so I thought there should be some explanation for that... I will send not so many emails, so maybe it makes sense to dispose it then

Comment: Samples are usually the shortest code necessary to point something out. They are not necessarily the way to go.